# How to disable stack trace in Non-Production environment of Node.js Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to disable stack trace in Non-Production environment of Node.js Application ?

Comment: Where do you want to hide it? What application you are running, how your errors are surfaced?

Comment: So if we set the environment variable NODE_ENV=production, then the stack trace will not be included in the built-in error handler. Same thing I m trying to do in my NODE_ENV=development environment.   App is running on Linux @NoNameProvided

Comment: Ok, but what is the built-in error handler? Written by you or provided by some framework? Provide some more information, as we won't be able to answer this question with the currently provided information.

Comment: It is basically a syntax error and with that error, we are getting the stack trace of application. I found this article but again this is helping me to hide only production stack trace - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#masking-and-logging-errors . Also I am using apollo server @NoNameProvided